# What is the difference between ng-valid[required], .ng-valid.required?

Tags: css, angular

I was going through https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html as exercise then I came through this piece of code:

```
.ng-valid[required], .ng-valid.required  {
  border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /* green */
}

.ng-invalid:not(form)  {
  border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}
```

Why are both of .ng-valid[required], .ng-valid.required  selectors used at the same time and cant we just replace this by only one of them?

Comment: i think .ng-valid[required] its look gor where required directive is preset or not and .ng-valid.required look for .required class in that perticular html tag.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `.ng-valid[required]` rule is valid for

```
<input class="ng-valid" required>
```

The `.ng-valid.required` rule is valid for

```
<input class="ng-valid required">
```

Both rules are valid for

```
<input class="ng-valid required" required>
```

Now you can choose which solution you want to use and remove the not necessary rules on your CSS.

Comment: so for the <input class="ng-valid required"> required not built in? its created by the user ?

Comment: yes the user have to check! the required (first example) can be detected by the browser.